# How do you properly subclass MvxCollectionViewSource?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

What's the trick to implementing a custom `MvxCollectionViewSource`?

I've subclassed it and have provided an implementation for `GetCell()`, but the resulting cells are not data bound. When I use an out of the box `MvxCollectionViewSource`, it works.

This is a 101 use case, so I must be doing something wrong. I am using MvvmCross 5.7. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: repro here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9w4q79zyih8q09r/CollectionViewRepro.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetCell` in `MvxCollectionViewSource`, `MvxTableViewSource` and other variants do the binding there. Hence, if you override that method, you are taking the responsibility of doing the binding.

If you simply want to provide your own Cell, you should override `GetOrCreateCellFor` instead. This method is used in `GetCell` to get the actual cell and bind it to the item found by calling `GetItemAt`.

So instead override `GetOrCreateCellFor`:

```
protected override UICollectionViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(
    UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
{
    var cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(MyCustomCell.Identifier, indexPath) as MyCustomCell;
    if (cell == null)
        cell = new MyCustomCell();

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you.